# What are you studying when you study a Harmonic Oscillator in QM?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, harmonic-oscillator, hilbert-space, measurement-problem, observables

This probably is a naive question - so please forgive a self-studier.

In the text I am studying, one builds a HO by placing a particle in a potential that increases quadratically from the origin. The Hamiltonian is presumed. Creation and annihilation operators are introduced, and consequently, the HO transitions from energy state to energy state.

My question arises due to a quote from the same text that I previously asked about in [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109135/2451) Phys.SE post:

> States of well defined energy are unphysical and 
>   never occur in Nature. They are incapable of 
>   changing in any way, and hence it is impossible 
>   to get a system into such a state.

Of course the math is beautiful and rigorous, but are we studying a pedagogical  model, or is there a context of reality?

Also, in that the creation and annihilation operators are not Hermitian, is this a clue that we are not dealing with real observables.

The source is notes by James Binney (Oxford)

http://www-thphys.physics.ox.ac.uk/people/JamesBinney/qb.pdf

which have subsequently been published as a text.

Comment: Can you add what textbook you're using to your question?

Comment: OP's other question about the same quote: http://physics.stackexchange.com/q/109135/29216

Comment: It is not an academic exercise. Please note that any symmetric potential when expanded in a series has as first dominant  term the x**2 term. Thus the harmonic oscillator is a good approximation for many physical situations given the right constants. Vibrations of classical strings are also harmonic oscillators, and are a basis for string theory for particles, after all.

Comment: @anna v Thanks for your comment. I appreciate the Taylor series expansion implications. My question is more directed to the well defined energy states and transitions between them in the context of the quote above. With regards,

Comment: that was answered in your previous question usning the heisenberg uncertainty principle argument : if you get a system in such a state there is a beginning of time, and measuring that it exists will have an end of time, a delta(t) which then gives a fuzzines to energy delta(E)

Comment: A stable atom if never ever disturbed will have its electrons at a sharp energy, but we will not be able to measure it!

Comment: For us spectroscopists, the harmonic oscillator is a model that describes the vibration spectra of diatomic molecules, which we can think of as two masses connected by a spring. Of course this model neglects the influence of rotation, anharmonicity, and molecular dissociation. These are addressed by the Morse potential and additional energy terms which are related to vibration-rotational coupling. But nonetheless, for low vibrational states the Morse potential looks a lot like the harmonic oscillator. These [slides](http://bit.ly/1ilydPX) illustrate the concept nicely.

Comment: @annav Dear Anna V - I only ask this out of ignorance: in that the quote says it is impossible to get a system into such a state, what does your remark - if you get a system into such a state - mean? Maybe the answer is implicit in your subsequent remark about a beginning of time. Perhaps I could impose on you to elaborate. Also, again please know that I am a real beginner, to the extent that you mention uncertainty, how can you simultaneously know you are in such a state and that you have a clearly knowable beginning of time. Thanks,

Comment: are you aware of the Heisenberg uncertainty principle http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heisenberg_uncertainty_principle ?

Comment: @BFTM Thank you for your comment and the link(which I up-triangled immediately). Perhaps you might like to write a short answer of a few lines regarding the idealized model and real world applications, including your link, and I would be happy to accept it. With regards,